# Dynamically publishing to multiple MQTT topics with Ardrino Sketch

Tags: arduino, ide, mqtt

I've got all the the code working reading the temperatures and humidity values but I' having great difficulties trying to get it to compile and publish correctly. i have two arrays declared where the readings are stored. - Working. I have successfully connected to my MQTT broker - working. I can print to the console - working. Bu for the life of me, I cannot seem to get the code correct for publishing the data using #include  and #include . This is the publishing loop where I print the data to the console and wish to use this to publish to my 8 different MQTT Topics.

```
// MQTT Setup MQTT: ID, server IP, port, username and password
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#define MQTT_VERSION MQTT_VERSION_3_1_1 

String sPayload;
char* cPayload;
String sTopic;
char* cTopic;
float pubtemp;

//This is the array for the topics
String station[8] ={
{"home/Front_Porch"},
{"home/Living_Room"},
{"home/Plant_Room"},
{"home/Office"},
{"appliances/Basement_Fridge"}, 
{"appliances/Basement_Freezr"},
{"appliances/Beer_Fridge"},
{"appliances/Pellet_Stove"}};

//These are the arrays for the variable readings
//Initialize the Temperature and Humidity Values
int Ch[8][2] = {{2120,00},{2120,00},{2120,00},{2120,00},{2120,00},{2120,00},
{2120,00},{2120,00}};
//This is the array for the low battery flag on the sensors
int Batt[8] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; // added 2/2/18 for battery status
```

here is the code that does the publishing

```
if (now - lastSampleTime >= fiveMinutes)
 {
lastSampleTime += fiveMinutes;
 // Serial.print (lastSampleTime);
 // Serial.println("***");
if (!client.connected()) {
 reconnect();
}
for (int m=0; m <=7; m++){
  Serial.print ("Channel ");
  Serial.print (m);
  Serial.print("\t");
  for (int n=0; n<=1; n++){
    if (n == 0) {
      Serial.print ("Temp ");
    //          Serial.print (Ch[m][n]);
      Serial.print ("\t");
      float mytemp= (Ch[m][n]);
      pubtemp=mytemp/10;
      Serial.print (pubtemp,1);
      Serial.print("\t");
      }
    else if (n == 1){
      Serial.print ("RH ");
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print (Ch[m][n]);
      Serial.print("\t");
      }
    }

   Serial.print (Batt[m]);
   Serial.print ("\t");
   Serial.print (station[m]);   
   Serial.println (" ");
 //Insert code here to publish the MQTT data before the next brace
 //This will publish a topic and associated data for each sensor
   StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;
   JsonObject& payload = jsonBuffer.createObject();
   payload["temperature"] = pubtemp;
   payload["humidity"] = Ch[m][1];
   payload["batt"] = Batt[m];  

   /This formats the json for the data and is working
   sPayload = "";
   payload.printTo(sPayload);
   cPayload = &sPayload[0u];
   Serial.println (cPayload);    

   This is where I'm having difficulties with the variable topics
   sTopic="";




 client.publish(station[m],cPayload);  This does not work.

 }
 //Publish a message when the full scan completes and this works
 client.publish("outTopic","Scan Complete");
 Serial.println ("Scan Complete");  
}
```

**Serial Output of Data**

1. Channel 0   Temp    19.8    RH  35  0   home/Front_Porch
2. {"temp":19.8,"humid":35,"batt":0}
3. Channel 1   Temp    67.7    RH  12  0   home/Living_Room
4. {"temp":67.7,"humid":12,"batt":0}
5. Channel 2   Temp    62.2    RH  24  0   home/Plant_Room
6. {"temp":62.2,"humid":24,"batt":0}
7. Channel 3   Temp    66.9    RH  16  0   home/Office
8. {"temp":66.9,"humid":16,"batt":0}
9. Channel 4   Temp    45.1    RH  0   0   appliances/Basement_Fridge
10. {"temp":45.1,"humid":0,"batt":0}
11. Channel 5  Temp    1.6 RH  0   0   appliances/Basement_Freezr
12. {"temp":1.6,"humid":0,"batt":0}pi
13. Channel 6  Temp    41.1    RH  0   0   appliances/Beer_Fridge
14. {"temp":41.1,"humid":0,"batt":0}
15. Channel 7  Temp    100.2   RH  0   0   appliances/Pellet_Stove
16. {"temp":100.2,"humid":0,"batt":0}
17. Scan Complete

The json output is working, and the topics are printing, but I can't seem to get the client.publish{"topic","payload") to work with the variable topic

Comment: I think I found my own answer, Changed String station[8] to char* station[8] and it works